# Running into error while running the app

Tags: redux, dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter, while running the app using `flutter run` command, it gives me this error.

```
The following StoreProviderError was thrown building StoreConnector<dynamic, dynamic>(dirty):


I/flutter ( 2958): Error: No StoreProvider<dynamic> found. To fix, please try:
I/flutter ( 2958):
I/flutter ( 2958):   * Using Dart 2 (required) by using the --preview-dart-2 flag
I/flutter ( 2958):   * Wrapping your MaterialApp with the StoreProvider<State>,
I/flutter ( 2958):   rather than an individual Route
I/flutter ( 2958):   * Providing full type information to your Store<State>,
I/flutter ( 2958):   StoreProvider<State> and StoreConnector<State, ViewModel>
I/flutter ( 2958):   * Ensure you are using consistent and complete imports.
I/flutter ( 2958):   E.g. always use `import 'package:my_app/app_state.dart';
```

Can someone help me out to solve this issue.

flutter doctor report:

```
  Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.24.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)
```

Comment: Please also add snippets of code that is throwing this error, and flutter doctor report.

Comment: I have updated the flutter doctor report @Ganapat